# how to hide a div that is empty and another div associated with it which may or maynot be empty?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, hide

I have a speech bubble called philosophy bubble which is just a div styled to look like a quote bubble and the sharepoint control is what fills up the content of the bubble but sometimes the bubble may not have any text and needs to  be hidden. Not just the bubble but also the text below which is like 'Mr. X's saying' should be hidden since the bubble is empty. How is is achieved in jquery?

```
<div class="philosophy-bubble">Quote goes here                  
</div>                              
<span class="credit">
Quoter..
</span>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you only want to hide the bubbles that have no text in them, you could do it this way:

```
$(".philosophy-bubble").each(function() {
    if (this.innerHTML.match(/\S/)) {
        $(this).hide().next(".credit").hide();

    }
});
```

Comment: Sweet...That was one delicious piece of code!! Thanks, Appreciated!The regular expression for empty string?? I guess??

Answer (score 1):

If you have access to the HTML, you could wrap both the `<div>` and `<span>` in a parent `<div>` tag.  The parent could then be hidden.

`$('.philsophy-bubble').parent().hide()`

If you have access to jQuery (I see you tagged this jQuery), you can use the `.next()` function which gets the next sibling (vertically).

Something like...

`$('.philosophy-bubble').hide().next().hide();`